# Android - Change Holo theme default blue color

Tags: android, colors, themes, extend

I would like to customize Holo theme by changing the default blue color to fit my company color.
Is there an easy way to do this?
Or I have to redefine the style of all components with blue parts, such as dialog titles, actionbar bottom line, pushed buttons, pickers, etc.

Comment: need to change default holo theme blue color with style.xml

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I cannot add anything more than this link:

http://android-holo-colors.com/

> **Android Holo Colors Generator**
>
> The Android Holo Colors Generator allows you to easily create Android
>   components such as editext or spinner with your own colours for your
>   Android application. It will generate all necessary nine patch assets
>   plus associated XML drawables and styles which you can copy straight
>   into your project.  If you have any question, please refer to the FAQ
>   or report an issue.

;-)

Comment: but it fail to change the edit text textfield_focused_holo_light of Dialogs !

Comment: What do I need to do with those files then? Where do they need to be put?

Answer (score 4):

As an addition to Waza Be's answer, you might want to [use this for styling the Action Bar:](http://jgilfelt.github.com/android-actionbarstylegenerator/#name=example&compat=holo&theme=light&actionbarstyle=solid&backColor=E4E4E4,100&secondaryColor=D6D6D6,100&tertiaryColor=F2F2F2,100&accentColor=33B5E5,100)

> The Android Action Bar Style Generator allows you to easily create a simple, attractive and seamless custom action bar style for your Android application. It will generate all necessary nine patch assets plus associated XML drawables and styles which you can copy straight into your project.

[This blog has an excellent tutorial on how to use it properly.](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/1240)

Comment: Please add content into your answer, not just a link. A link can be deleted or moved making the answer useless

Comment: it fail to change the edit text textfield_focused_holo_light of Dialogs, dialog fragment ! we need to set theme for custom dialogfragment  that is the pain point!!

Comment: Unfortunately that blog with the excellent tutorial on how to use it properly is no longer reachable. Any other examples on how to use the files?