# android styles and themes - how to get main theme color

Tags: android, android-theme

I created my own style which I use as theme for my app. It's based on android default holo light with some modification. As main color I use everywhere `@android:color/holo_blue_light` It worked ok with older versions of Android but when I got Android 4.2.2 device I noticed that it's possible to change the theme in device settings to ex. Mint. Then part of  my app interface is in mint color (the things I didn't changed in default holo light theme) and part is in holo_blue_light.

The question is how to modify my style, instead of using `@android:color/holo_blue_light` to have main theme color (which in some cases will be blue light but in some cases ex. mint) (what label to use to get main theme color?).

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Yar this links may helpful for you change your theme color and even to change actionbar [follow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13257219/android-change-holo-theme-default-blue-color)

Comment: Thanks for help. But it's the direction I'm looking for. They describe how to define own style. My question is how to get default theme colour?

Comment: Just to be sure we understand well each other - in Android 4.2 or higher go to Settings/Display/Theme and here you can select between Default/Mint/Mocha/Raspberry. How to get this color which is selected here?